# Find item with max() for two values in list of dicts with Python

Tags: python

I have a data structure with a list of json encoded lists containing dicts. Each dict represents data about an image.

I would like to find the dict with the largest "width" and largest "height" values for all dicts contained in that entire structure.

What would be a pythonic way to do it? Can a generator expression be used?

```
[
'[{"imagePath": "full/efd5234517d9d20a7a47c3bf1860f6150a3bab6f.jpg", "percentageOfFirst": 0.2866666666666667, "height": 215.0, "width":
214.0, "imageSourceURL": "http://host/ca/I/iamge.png", "backgroundColor": null, "averageColor": "(197, 199, 203)", "md5": "cbd2eba6eb26b907901d1c932ab43a4f"}]',

'[{"imagePath": "full/72c2a2dabbbb2d3b245fafe85827b5b8f4df046b.jpg", "percentageOfFirst": 0.014079601990049751, "height": 62.0, "width":
275.0, "imageSourceURL": "http://host/logo.png", "backgroundColor": "white", "captionText": "SIEMNS", "averageColor": "(252, 253, 254)", "md5": "9951343e3ba782ba08549b2e14d8392c"}, {"imagePath": "full/ffe1119f36aa46eb72b52b4ff07c349fa32bea2e.jpg", "percentageOfFirst": 0.36909013605442176, "height": 523.0, "width":
400.0, "imageSourceURL": "http://host/image.png", "backgroundColor": "white", "averageColor": "(227, 228, 231)", "md5": "d9bee142cc4bdd457a1acfc8d37c8066"},
{"imagePath": "full/38ffd6eb550a1560ce736994ca85577d4df478e4.jpg", "percentageOfFirst": 0.6995127353266888, "height": 452.0, "width":
450.0, "imageSourceURL": "http://host/image.png", "backgroundColor": "white", "captionText": "nuMusmun", "averageColor": "(250, 250, 250)", "md5": "1b18fc0f9df4c1b2ca20ecda6537d5ac"}, {"imagePath": "full/ee3442b404f1a6f3fb77b448d475fbcee8b328b8.jpg", "percentageOfFirst": 0.10946727549467275, "height": 853.0, "width":
584.0, "imageSourceURL": "http://host/iamge.png", "backgroundColor": "white", "averageColor": "(202, 206, 212)", "md5": "a9cd43327d0f64aaf0ec5aafa3acf8ac"}]', '[{"imagePath": "full/5e24e5c1edf925bfddc0d66a483846729bcc9cbf.jpg", "percentageOfFirst": 0.22071519795657726, "height": 87.0, "width":
100.0, "imageSourceURL": "http://host/photos/image.png", "backgroundColor": "white", "averageColor": "(239, 239, 239)", "md5": "090b186f86de5c3a06ddea7e2c4bfd1a"}]'
]
```

Comment: Given data is malformed. please share the data by `print` or fix the data above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [
# your list
]

import json

# Parse your JSONs
parsed = map(json.loads, lst)

# Join sublists into one big list
joined = sum(parsed, [])

# Find the maximum
max_size = max(joined, key=lambda d: (d['width'] * d['height']))

print(max_size)
```

Note that your requirement "the dict with the largest "width" and largest "height"" is inconsistent: how would you compare a 800x600 and a 900x500 image? So I chose to find the image with the maximum size. You can adjust `key` to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply a key function to max().

If you have:

```
x = [{'image':1, 'width':5, 'height':5}, {'image':2, 'width':6, 'height':6}]
```

Then

```
max(x, key = lambda i:i['width'])
```

would get the dictionary with the highest width value.

Answer (score 0):

Well after you have actual dicts:

```
res = max(list_of_dicts, key=lambda d: d['width'])
```